# How to prevent XML files from indexing by Google on Rails with Nginx setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, seo

I have my project setup on Rails & Nginx. How do I prevent sitemap XML files from begin indexed by Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following in your virtual host file (It requires the file to exist physically)

```
location ~* \.(txt|log|xml|css|js)$ {
    add_header X-Robots-Tag noindex;
}
```

Comment: on adding this i cannot access dynamically generated xml file at /sitemap.xml , getting 404 error The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

for physically existing xml files this is working fine.. thanks